# System process uses max CPU on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, browser, flash, cpu-usage

When playing something on youtube and/or while anything using adobe flash is active, "ntoskrnl.exe" uses one whole core constantly. I tried in opera and internet explorer. It happens in both.

What is "System" doing and/or how to make it stop doing it?

I'm on windows 10 home, 64-bit.
Acer Extensa 2511-376F, Intel Core i3 (5. Gen) 5005U / 2 GHz, 4 GB (1 x 4 GB) DDR3L SDRAM SO DIMM 204-PIN. [Full specification](https://www.proshop.dk/Baerbar/Acer-Extensa-2511-376F/2528032)

Comment: It might help to also specify the make/model of your computer. If the computer is old, the answer is obvious.

Comment: @Appleoddity It's Acer Extensa 2511-376F, Intel Core i3 (5. Gen) 5005U / 2 GHz, 4 GB (1 x 4 GB) DDR3L SDRAM SO DIMM 204-PIN. [Full specification](https://www.proshop.dk/Baerbar/Acer-Extensa-2511-376F/2528032). What would be the obvious answer if too old?!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the info. It’s important for others to help diagnose the issue. If the machine was old the obvious answer would be that flash and media intensive sites are overloading your CPU because it is old. I wouldn’t think your system qualifies as old, but maybe.